# Difference between http.handle and gorilla.mux when implementing tus-file-uploader

Tags: go, gorilla, tus

I am trying to implement a tus-file-uploader (tus.io) based on the exmaples provided on their website. Everything works fine until I switch from

```
http.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", handler))
```

to

```
r.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", handler))
```

having declared r like this:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
```

Using the gorilla router makes the tus-server reply with 404 when trying to call the PATCH-Request to upload a file.

Question: In which ways is http-Handle different from r.Handle given in the example above? Maybe it does not serve PATCH-Requests?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved it:**

```
r.PathPrefix("/files/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/files/", handler))
```

is the correct way to implement the tusd-uploader-handler